# Running "conda update --all" causes an error. [MacOS]

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I wanted to update my conda, so I ran `conda update -all`, but I unfortunately kept getting the same error. That there was some file missing. First it said that there was a module called `six` missing, so I tried to install it. I reran it, but still it said that it and python3.6 were missing. I tried running `conda clean --all` and then rerunning `conda update --all` to fix it, but I keep getting the same error. `FileNotFoundError(2, "No such file or directory: '/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/bin/python3.6'")`
I'm currently unsure on what I am supposed to do to make it work or how to fix this.

````
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: | Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-nbextension", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.nbextensions import main
  File "/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
  File "/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .config_manager import BaseJSONConfigManager
  File "/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/config_manager.py", line 14, in <module>
    from six import PY3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'

WARNING conda.core.link:run_script(818): pre-unlink script failed for package conda-forge::bqplot-0.11.2-py36_0
consider notifying the package maintainer
\ + /Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/bin/beakerx uninstall
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/bin/beakerx", line 7, in <module>
    from beakerx import run
  File "/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/beakerx/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .plot import *
  File "/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/beakerx/plot/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .chart import *
  File "/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/beakerx/plot/chart.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame
  File "/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 423, in <module>
    from dateutil import parser as _date_parser
  File "/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._parser import parse, parser, parserinfo
  File "/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 42, in <module>
    import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'

WARNING conda.core.link:run_script(818): pre-unlink script failed for package conda-forge::beakerx-1.2.0-py36_1000
consider notifying the package maintainer
/ WARNING conda.core.link:run_script(818): pre-unlink script failed for package conda-forge::ipympl-0.2.1-py36_0
consider notifying the package maintainer
| WARNING conda.core.link:run_script(818): pre-unlink script failed for package conda-forge::gmaps-0.8.2-py_0
consider notifying the package maintainer
/ WARNING conda.core.link:run_script(818): pre-unlink script failed for package conda-forge::qt-5.6.2-h4e759b2_11
consider notifying the package maintainer
failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(507): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::dask-core-1.1.0-py_0'.
FileNotFoundError(2, "No such file or directory: '/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/bin/python3.6'")
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

FileNotFoundError(2, "No such file or directory: '/Users/mahmoudshihab/anaconda3/bin/python3.6'")```
````

Comment: What version is your python? Run "python -V" and paste results

Comment: ```python -V
Python 3.6.7```